# Way to have hoc withErrorHandler without using axios interceptors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, error-handling, axios

I would like to create a wrapping higher order component for other components that intercepts errors and displays the message. Axios has built in interceptors that make it easy through `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` while rendering a modal if `error: true`. I am having trouble writing it in pure Typescript and was wondering if there was any way to do it while managing the error state through a dispatch handler that catch the errors.

```
    componentWillMount() {
      this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
        this.setState({ error: null })
        return req
      })
      this.resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
        res => res,
        error => {
          this.setState({ error: error })
        }
      )
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.reqInterceptor)
      axios.interceptors.response.eject(this.resInterceptor)
    }
```

example wrapping

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withErrorHandler(WrappedContainer, axios))
```

Comment: I'm not really clear... is the code you've shown how you want it to work? If so what errors do you get? What code do you have for `withErrorHandler`?

Comment: This seems to be a task for Redux middleware, which isn't even mentioned in the question.